# how to implement a handshake in netty datagram communication?

Tags: java, udp, netty, blocking, handshake

I achieved communication over TCP with netty Which I'm very proud of. I now need some UDP as well because I'm writing a game and action games should probably communicate gamestate, input, etc. Via UDP. I'm currently rewriting Networkcode for the game so my former TCP communication (announce server existence to broker, client asking broker for Serverlist, etc.) will become UDP comm. Some stuff like input prob. Doesn't need handshakes but something like announcing a server to the broker needs to be announced reliably.

I thought of something like using a future for this but I'm not getting any smarter googling or even reading "netty in action" Which barely touches UDP.

How can I write a handler that sends a UDP message and waits for an answer?

Basically I want the server to say "here I am, these are my details" and then make the broker go "got it, will tell people about it" and then and only then the server should start to do other stuff. Sounds blocking to me but I still use nio for this right?

Small code example, link or explanation to understand the basics of this would be appreciated.

Comment: please check netty example socksproxy, see how the server deal with Socks5InitialRequest msg

Comment: So if you meant this https://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/socksproxy/SocksServerHandler.html this is not what i meant. Or im just not seeing it. Can you elaborate? Thx